# Reward function for learning to play Curve Fever game with DQN

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I've made a simple version of Curve Fever also known as "Achtung Die Kurve". I want the machine to figure out how to play the game optimally. I copied and slightly modified an existing DQN from some Atari game examples that is made with Google's Tensorflow.

I'm tyring to figure out an appropriate reward function. Currently, I use this reward setup:

- 0.1 for every frame it does not crash
- -500 for every crash

Is this the right approach? Do I need to tweak the values? Or do I need a completely different approach?

Comment: Did you manage to get the DQN to work?

Comment: Yes, I implemented the scoring like described below.

Comment: So -1 for dying, +1 for killing. Did you use any small constant value for surviving?

Comment: I first used a small constant as a reward for surviving but that did not turn out like I wanted to. Keep in mind that training such a network can take a couple of nights before any positive result is achieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reward of -500 can destroy your network. You should scale the rewards to the values between 1 and -1. (Also scale the input image between -1 and 1 or 0 and 1).

Just give your network a reward of -1 for crashing and a reward of +1 once an enemy crashes. Without enemies a reward of -1 for crashing should be enough. Having a small constant positive living reward can be beneficial in some situations (like when the network has to decide between two inevitable crashes of which one will happen faster than the other) but it will also make the learning of the Q-function more complicated. You can just try with and without a constant reward and see what works best.

The example with an inevitable crash also shows why you should not use a small negative living reward. In such a case the network would chose the path of the fastest crash, while delaying the crash as much as possible would be the better strategy in that situation.

Answer (score 0):

It's best when the reward function exactly encodes the goal you want the agent to pursue. In *Curve Fever*, the goal is to be the last player alive. If you used a reward function that just gave a reward for staying in the game, the best policy would be to draw the game out indefinitely. You probably want the agent to win as quickly as possible, so you should actually give a small negative reward each timestep and some positive reward for winning a round. This is a *hurry up and win* reward function.

Comment: This is true. But the first thing I want to achieve is to let the agent alone in the world and make it not crash into its own tail. I give a positive reward for staying alive and a big punish for crashing, but I'm not sure this is the correct approach.